# Azure AD B2C Insufficient privileges to complete the operation while using Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have started with https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIdConnect-DotNet as the base

Created sign in profile in Azure B2C preview.

Sign in flows works wonderfully with MFA, used custom  pages with the help of https://github.com/azureadquickstarts/b2c-azureblobstorage-client/.

CSS and styling works . However I realized that sign up form will be less onerous with Javascript autocomplete.

B2C dues to security issues had prohibited Javascript.

So I filled email/password with B2C flows and then decided to redirect it my own page within a mvc route of my original project. This one uses https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-web/blob/master/WebAppGraphAPI/Controllers/UsersController.cs as an inspiration for Graph API.

I am able to successfully get token via

```
adClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient( serviceRoot, async () => await GetAppTokenAsync());
```

However the following fails with "Insufficient privileges to complete" exception

```
userResult = (User)adClient.Users.GetByObjectId(userObjectID).ExecuteAsync().Result;
```

I have tried doing the following https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6dd08794-ab89-4513-91e5-546c97a85adc/graph-client-throwing-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation-on-creating-ad-user?forum=WindowsAzureAD as well as try https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console/issues/27 powershell trick

powershell fails with

C:\Users\Karan\Desktop\dev> $msolcred = Get-Credential cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1 Supply values for the following parameters: Credential PS C:\Users\Karan\Desktop\dev> Connect-MsolService -credential $msolcred Connect-MsolService : Exception of type 'http://Microsoft.Online .Administration.Automation.MicrosoftOnlineException' was thrown. At line:1 char:1 + Connect-MsolService -credential $msolcred + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : OperationStopped: (:) [Connect-MsolService], Mic rosoftOnlineException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 0x800488D6,http://Microsoft.Online .Administration.Autom ation.ConnectMsolService .....

also tried steps mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet

Also added graph API permissions "Read / write directory" in B2C AD here 
[image]

also ticked more options in Windows Azure Active Directory

As well as ticked then in Old portal.

[image: Clicked on grant permissions too]

Comment: Did you click on the "Grant Permissions" button as well?

Comment: Yes I just did. Still running into same error "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: It takes a bit (I want to say 1 hour max?) for that to take effect. If it still doesn't work, can you copy your access token into jwt.calebb.net and see put a screenshot of the output. I'd like to confirm if that you are not getting the scopes you requested.

Comment: Attached decoded JWT

Comment: After four days wait . Still permissions have not percolated

Comment: Hi @Saca, The solution given below works in local, not when we deploy it to azure as a web app

Comment: Hi, deploying to Azure web app also works

Answer (score 0):

This has been resolved. I had to create a new application. It was clearly written "Do not modify" against my B2C generated application - and I was modifying permissions for that. So I added a new application and granted that read and write directory. My mistake.

[image]

Comment: Note that when you update extension property using this strategy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31619774/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions - then do not use app id of newly created application but instead use the app id of b2c-extensions-.. do not modify app